# Run a function after ajax call is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have different pages  ex1.php ,ex2.php, ex3.php

All of these pages have different ajax call and they have some code in the respective success function.

I want to run a function myfunc() when i get any response in any of these ajax calls?? Is it posssible??

Can i use jquery complete???

I have only one js file which is common to all these files where i have myfunc() written

ex1.php

$.ajax()

ex2.php

$.ajax()

ex3.php

$.ajax()

test.js which is loaded in all these php file has myfunc

Comment: `$.ajaxStart(myfunc1); $.ajaxStop(myfunc2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) event handler

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(myfunc);
```

Comment: i had tried $.ajaxComplete(myfunc); now i tried $( document ).ajaxComplete(myfunc); it worked

Answer (score 0):

You should call your myfunc on the success of the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
url: "ex2.php"
}).done(function() {
  myfunc()
});
```